# Understanding Cyclic Codes

Tags: number-theory, coding-theory

If I have a generator polynomial, g(x) which divides x<sup>9</sup> + 1 but does not have x+1 as a factor and I have to prove that 111111111 is a valid codeword after detecting by the code.

Here, Since x<sup>9</sup> + 1 = (x<sup>3</sup> + 1)(x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + 1 ) = (x+1)(x<sup>2</sup> + x + 1)(x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + 1 ) . Here, (x<sup>2</sup> + x + 1) can't be broken into factors of (x+1). If it were (x<sup>2</sup>+1), then I can write x<sup>2</sup>+1 = (x+1)(x+1) but it is not the case here. Now, Since, g(x) divides it, it means, x<sup>9</sup> + 1 = g(x)z(x), where z(x) is some polynomial in 'x'.

So, (x<sup>9</sup> + 1) = (x+1)(x<sup>2</sup> + x + 1)(x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + 1 ) =  g(x)z(x).

As g(x) does not have (x+1) as a factor, the possible choices for g(x) are :

1. (x<sup>2</sup> + x + 1)
2. (x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + 1 )
3. (x<sup>2</sup> + x + 1)*(x<sup>6</sup> + x<sup>3</sup> + 1 )

In all these 3 cases, g(x) divides 111111111 at receiver side, So, 111111111 is a valid codeword.
Can anyone please check it and please correct me if I am wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: IMHO a reasoning missing why $x^6+x^3+1$ is irreducible. Also "As, $g(x)$ is not a factor of $(x+1)$" should be "As, $g(x)$ is not a multiply of $(x+1)$". Looks OK.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alexey Burdin. I could do rest of the things.

Comment: This question is about cyclic codes and not about CRCs at all. I have edited the title accordingly.

Comment: ok Thank you ! @DilipSarwate